# How to tell whether a building is 長屋【ながや】建{だて} or 共同{きょうどう}住宅{じゅうたく}

Tags: word-choice, nuances, definitions

The 国勢{こくせい}調査{ちょうさ} census asks every habitant of Japan to tell whether they live in a `一戸建【いっこだて】` (stand-alone house) , a `長屋【ながや】建{だて}(テラスハウスを含む)`, a `共同{きょうどう}住宅{じゅうたく}`, or `その他{ほか}` (other).

**QUESTION:** What is the difference between a 長屋建 and a 共同住宅?

If it is determined by the number of floors, please explain exactly where the threshold is.

---

[image]

Comment: Related but different: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24778/how-to-tell-whether-a-building-is-%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3-or-%E3%82%A2%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88

Comment: Did you click that 「解説を表示する」 link to check how they defined 長屋建て?

Comment: @naruto: I don't know how I managed to not see that link... and now I can't go back to check it :-/

Comment: ここに絵と説明が・・・http://www.stat.go.jp/data/kokusei/2010/users-g/word3.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It essentially seems to be based on whether the entrance is shared or not. If there is one door per household it is 長屋建. If there is a hall entrance it is a 共同住宅.
The number of floors has no relevance, even a one-floor building can be a 共同住宅.

From http://www.stat.go.jp/data/kokusei/2010/users-g/word3.htm:

> ## 長屋建
>
> > 二つ以上の住宅を一棟に建て連ねたもので，各住宅が壁を共通にし，それぞれ別々に外部への出入口をもっているもの
> >     いわゆる「テラス・ハウス」も含みます。
>
> [image: 長屋建]
>
> ## 共同住宅
>
> > 棟の中に二つ以上の住宅があるもので，廊下・階段などを共用しているものや二つ以上の住宅を重ねて建てたもの
> >     ※　1階が店舗で，2階以上が住宅になっている建物も含みます。
> >     ※　建物の階数により「1・2階建」，「3～5階建」，「6～10階建」，「11～14階建」，「15階建以上」に５区分しています。また，平成17年調査から世帯が住んでいる階についても，建物の階数と同様に五つに区分しています。
>
> [image: 共同住宅]